# How to Set Attribute Value of <A> Tag in live HTMLDocument with quotes around it?

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, vb6, webbrowser-control

Bascially, all i'm trying to do is change the value of an attribute (such as the TARGET attribute of an A anchor tag) to "_TOP" if the attribute exists, if it doesn't exist, (if IsNull returns True) then I just create the attribute and set the value to "_TOP".

The problem is, it almost always sets it without quotes around it, and even if i try to set it with quotes by setting .value = Chr(34) & "_TOP" & Chr(34) then what it does is it sets SINGLE QUOTES around the quotes I place (it's like a bad joke) and turns up in the HTML as `'"_TOP"'` (lol), and if I set it normally, its just saved as `<a href="..." target=_TOP>some link</a>` (without quotes).

```
Dim attTargetAttribute As IHTMLDOMAttribute2 ' IHTMLDOMAttribute2 is the IE6.0+
' interface of the IHTMLDOMAttribute (which is I think IE5.5) it goes up to 4.

' aHtmlElement is just a valid/working/tested IHTMLElement ive set earlier.
' just a simple "A" / Anchor tag <A href="...">.

If IsNull(aHtmlElement.Attributes.getNamedItem("target")) Then

  Set attTargetAttribute = aHtmlElement.ownerDocument.createAttribute("target")
  aHtmlElement.Attributes.setNamedItem attTargetAttribute
Else

  Set attTargetAttribute = aHtmlElement.Attributes.getNamedItem("target")
End If

  attTargetAttribute.value = "_TOP"
```

I've changed the above variable names & turned vars into strings ("target") etc to make it easier to read for anyone reading.

I have wasted heaps of hours on this, MSDN docs are as usual horrid, there is no real documentation or tutorial on this stuff either. I've even tried using .nodeValue instead of .value to do the setting, but makes no difference. Also, I've tried (in the Else section) removing the attribute and re-creating + re-adding it from scratch to see if this would make a difference, but it didn't.

Of course, quotes are important because if you try to perform an action (call a method) on this element or use it later, you will get the dreaded "unspecified error". I do this through the WebBrowser Control in VB6, but same principle should apply everywhere... C#/.NET/JavaScript etc as it seems to be DOM related).

Any ideas anyone? Been on this for over 2 days now, thank you to all who've taken the time to read this.

**UPDATE:** since posting we realized that if we pass the attribute name in uppercase, then the value is saved with double quotes around it. although this is not a real solution (just a temporary one), i am still looking for answers if anyone has one and accepting any thoughts you may have about this in this post. However, the temporary solution has created another sub question, being a post about the problems that arise from using this temporary solution. The sub question related to this temporary solution is located at the following link for those who may find it useful or interesting to read about, and for those who would like to contribute to this discussion further: [Must pass uppercase to set MSHTML element attribute (.setAttribute) correctly, why? And CaseInsensitive .setAttribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226106/must-pass-uppercase-to-set-mshtml-element-attribute-setattribute-correctly-w)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/fak4b/

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links[i].getAttribute('target'));
    if (links[i].getAttribute('target') != '_TOP') {
        links[i].setAttribute('target', '_TOP');
    }
}
```

Comment: @mrtcherman thanks, i've done this using .setAttribute and it does the exact same thing, saving at target=_top if i set it normally, and target='"_top"' if i try to pass normal double quotes around it ( Chr(34) ) - any ideas why it may be doing this? I get the element using .Document.All.tags("A")... this shouldn't change anything should it?

Comment: Why are you trying to put quotes around it at all? The call does that for you. That's why it gets wrapped in single quotes when you manually add double quotes. single quotes are valid markup and it forces the method to use them in order to escape the double quotes.

Comment: @mrtcherman i've just tried with Document.getelementsbytagname("A") and its still yielding the same results, driving me crazy :(. I am not trying to put double quotes around them manually, just tried it to see if it will save with double quotes. im trying to same them normally and its result is no quotes, not even single quotes around the attribute value. i need to have quotes around the value because if i dont the html tag/element does not work since its invalid html in the webbrowser control.

Comment: Sets it without quotes? What browser are you using? That just doesn't happen.

Comment: @mrtcherman of course, ive tried doing it without quotes, thats how i do it normally, im using the webbrowser control which uses IE 7 as its default rendering engine. (updated my last comment above).

Comment: @mrtcherman this is REALLY interesting, ive been doing some playing around in the immediate window while compiler is in run-time mode, and when i do a .setAttribute with the name in capitals, ie: TARGET as follows: .setAttribute "TARGET", "_top"  it ALWAYS saves "_top" with quotes, regardless of the case of the value, as long as the name is sent in capitals, the value is saved in quotes all the time. this is really interesting, any idea why its doing this? and when using .removeAttribute it is case sensitive, so removing "target" will not work if you send "targeT". wow, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @mrtcherman really odd, will need to post another question about this, since the iFlags parameter of .getAttribute dont even work and it never returns anything if i specify case insensitive (default), and must specify case sensitive and pass the right case in .getAttribute in order for it to return the value of the attribute. really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Life hack: 
Put one or more white-spaces before attribute value.

Example:

```
var head   = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var metaEl = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("meta");

metaEl.SetAttribute("HTTP-EQUIV", "X-UA-Compatible");
metaEl.SetAttribute("CONTENT"   , " IE=11"         ); // <= one white-space before attribute value.

head.AppendChild(metaEl);
```